# Haskell program to extract the first words of each line of a text file

Tags: strings, haskell

```
isLineTerminator c = c == '\r' || c == '\n'
leadWords [] = []
leadWords cs =
    let (pre, suf) = break isLineTerminator cs
    in  (head (words pre)) : case suf of 
                            ('\r':'\n':rest) -> leadWords rest
                            ('\r':rest)      -> leadWords rest
                            ('\n':rest)      -> leadWords rest
                            _                -> []

fixLines :: String -> String
fixLines input = unlines (leadWords input)

interactWith function inputFile outputFile = do
    input <- readFile inputFile
    writeFile outputFile (function input)

main = mainWidth myFunction
  where mainWidth function = do
            args <- getArgs
            case args of 
                [input, output] -> interactWith function input output
                _               -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
        myFunction = fixLines
```

Much of this program is written by the author of the book on Haskell that I'm reading, so I assume that much of it is good. However, my part is in altering the `leadWords` function. Does it look like a:

1. readable, elegant function?
2. efficient and optimized function?

Comment: Why did you alter it? What was wrong with the original?

Comment: The original did not extract the first word. it just converted the lines from Windows formate to Linux format.

Answer (score 2):

## Errors

The code block above is an example where your program will fail. Any empty line will lead to an empty list in `words ""` and therefore to `head []`, which calls `error`.

## Standard library

That being said, there are some other issues with your code. You use `unlines` in `fixLines`, yet `leadWords` is essentially `lines`, although it also uses `head . words` internally. If we rewrite `leadWords` with `map`, we end up with

```
leadWords = map (head . words) . lines
```

which immediately shows the possible error on empty lines. Still, we can fix this if we write another function:

```
firstWord :: String -> Maybe String
firstWord xs = case words xs of
                   (x : _) -> Just x
                   _       -> Nothing
```

Now we can use `mapMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` to write `leadWords`:

```
leadWords :: String -> [String]
leadWords = mapMaybe firstWord . lines
```

## Type signatures

Other than that, you should really add type signatures to your top-level functions. Only `fixLines` has one, and its not clear why that one got special handling.

## Code complexity

`main` is overly complicated, too. We can just inline `mainWidth`, as its local binding doesn't yield any more comfort:

```
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of 
        [input, output] -> interactWith fixLines input output
        _               -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"
```

Alternatively, we can provide `mainWith` *as top level function* and use that in `main`.

## Complete code

If we apply all remarks given above, we end up with something similar to the following code:

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

mainWith :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
mainWith f = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of 
        [input, output] -> interactWith f input output
        _               -> putStrLn "error: exactly two arguments needed"

fixLines :: String -> String
fixLines = unlines . leadWords

main :: IO ()
main = mainWith fixLines

-- for completeness

leadWords :: String -> [String]
leadWords = mapMaybe firstWord . lines

firstWord :: String -> Maybe String
firstWord xs = case words xs of
                     (x : _) -> Just x
                     _       -> Nothing

-- That's just personal preference, your style is fine.
interactWith :: (String -> String) -> FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
interactWith f input output = readFile input >>= writeFile output . f
```

In short:

- add type signatures to top-level functions
- don't use `head` on lists that might be empty
- use standard library types when possible (`Maybe`)
- use standard library functions when possible (`map`, `lines` and `mapMaybe`)